# How to convert a multiple columns into 2 columns in Excel in the following format?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Name    F1  F2  F3
John    a   b   d
Mindy   d   a   c
Joe     c   b   e
Alan    a   c   

Into The below Format

Name    Fields
John    a
John    b
John    d
Mindy   d
Mindy   a
Mindy   c
Joe     c
Joe     b
Joe     e
Alan    a
Alan    c
```

Comment: Scan all rows in your first table (`for i=2 to LastRow`). For each row keep name (`MyName = Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(i, 1)`). If cell content is not null, copy to desired place (`Worksheets("MyOtherSheet").Cells(k, 1)=MyName; Worksheets("MyOtherSheet").Cells(k, 2)=Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(i, q)`). `i`, `q` and `k` keep track of row/columns.

Answer (score 1):

In **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$9999,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0))
```

and copy down.  In **F1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one which tries to allow for a variable number of columns.

In (say) L2:-

```
=A2
```

In L3

```
=IF(COUNTIF(L$1:L2,L2)>=COUNTA(INDEX($B$2:$J$10,MATCH(L2,$A$2:$A$10,0),)),INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(L2,$A$2:$A$10,0)+1),L2)
```

In M2:-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$J$10,MATCH(L2,$A$2:$A$10,0),COUNTIF($L$1:$L2,L2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two formulas to get as you want. Put this formula into cell `B8` is to get second column:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS($B$2:$D$5)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS($B$2:$D$5),COLUMNS($B$2:$D$5))+1)
```

Also this formula is to get first column, put it into cell `A8` and fill down both formulas:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,CEILING(COUNTA($B$8:B8)/COLUMNS($B$2:$D$5),1))
```

You can get [my example file.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1MDRmTGhQVU1OVWs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution for you.

```
Sub Rearrange()
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
s1.Activate
n = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
k = 1
For i = 1 To n
namee = Cells(i, 1).Value
For j = 2 To 4
numberr = Cells(i, j).Value
s2.Cells(k, 1) = namee
s2.Cells(k, 2) = numberr
k = k + 1
Next
Next
End Sub
```